# Assignment Operator &= W3Schools

Tags: c#, math, logic, bit, bitwise-operators

I am trying to understand how, in practical terms the code from W3Schools works

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int x = 5;
      x &= 3;
      Console.WriteLine(x);  
     }
  }
}
```

The result of the operation is 1.

Does anyone with can explain how it works bitwise in details all the steps?

I tried to look at [Bitwise and shift operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-), but it is still doesn't make much sense to me. What is the maths logic behind it?

Comment: `x &= 3` == `x = x & 3` == `x = 5 & 3`. Try to "AND" those two numbers in binary and you get 1. Simple as that. Here it is in binary: `0101 AND 0011 = 0001`.

Comment: Yes, thank you just figured it out. YouTube video Coding Shorts: Demystifying Bitwise Operators in C# at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWCUoLCRY38 helped to refresh my memory.

Answer (score 0):

& means "AND" two numbers' binary formats.

5 in binary format = 0101

3 in binary format = 0011

when you "AND" them, you get 0001 and it makes 1 in decimal form.